# How to make label, text-input and error message same line even when using mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve a few things with this code, but without success:

1. That the label will be closer to the text-input box and not so far to the left ("Name:", "Age:")
2. That when I zoom-in like in mobile view, the label and the text box will be at the same line, and not that the box will go down a little bit
3. That the `is-invalid` error will display to the right of the text box and not below it

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <label for="name" class="col-form-label label col-xl-3">Name:</label>
                <div class="form-group is-invalid">
                    <input type="text" dir="auto" class="form-control is-invalid" id="name" name="name" style="width:250px;">
                    <div id="name_error" class="invalid-feedback"><p>Error</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>            
            <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <label for="age" class="col-form-label label col-xl-3">Age:</label>
                <div class="form-group is-invalid">
                    <input type="text" dir="auto" class="form-control col-12 is-invalid" id="age" name="age" style="width:250px;">
                    <div id="age_error" class="invalid-feedback">Error</div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use col-sm class too . try : `<label for="age" class="col-form-label label col-xl-3 col-sm-1">Age:</label>` and read the doc ;)

Comment: Haha yes I need to read more. Do you have any more fundamental issues I must fix in my code? Something that's not well written according to the Bootstrap docs?

Comment: looks fine beside the missing sm class ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <div class="row form-group d-flex justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <label for="name" class="col-form-label col-2 text-right">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" dir="auto" class="form-control is-invalid col-6" id="name" name="name">
                <div id="name_error" class="invalid-feedback col-2"><p>Error</p></div> 
            </div> 

            <div class="row form-group d-flex justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <label for="age" class="col-form-label col-2 text-right">Age:</label>
                <input type="text" dir="auto" class="form-control col-6 is-invalid" id="age" name="age">
                <div id="age_error" class="invalid-feedback col-2">Error</div>
            </div>   
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```